# Excel VBA Code to select opened Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I've done lots of search through various website but to no avail.

Previously I create simple VBA to select XLS from automatic-generated-XLS which created by a software as below. This excel does not have any file type at it's end because it was not saved anywhere yet and i'm not planning to save it.

```
Sub Test()

    Windows("All Jobs").Activate

End Sub
```

Lately, the software generate new file name "All Jobs (0 - XX)" which XX could be any number from 1 to 100. So, the code above does not work anymore. Adding * does not help.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.
Zaiem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop thru the `Windows` collection to check the caption of each window. Try this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim myWindow As Window
    For Each myWindow In Windows
        If Left(myWindow.Caption, 8) = "All Jobs" Then myWindow.Activate: Exit Sub
    Next myWindow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all `Workbooks` in `Application` (Excel), and if the current workbook's name is `Like "All Jobs" & "*"` >> this is your desired workbook.

**Note**: verify that you need to `Activate` the workbook, usually it is not needed.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim AllJobSWB As Workbook

For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    If WB.Name Like "All Jobs" & "*" Then
        Set AllJobSWB = WB ' set the matched workbook
        Exit For
    End If
Next WB

' if you must activate the workbook, use the line below
AllJobSWB.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: @ZaiemOthman what error ? at which line ? anyway I saw you alread accepted the "ANSWER" above

Comment: Sorry as I was absent yesterday. An error show at "AllJobSWB.Active". Runtime error'91'. Object variable or With block variable not set. i'm not sure what it mean.

Comment: You do not need to use `&` operator. You can just ut `*` at the end of the string; `"All Jobs*"`.